# Need to inner join all colums from 2 tables with same column names

Tags: php, mysql, inner-join

I saw numbers of answers for this questions but all answers seem to point to the same result.
I need to inner join 2 tables with one column that has the same name in both.  My code:

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM Bets
INNER JOIN Users ON Bets.UserID = Users.UserID
INNER JOIN Games ON Bets.GameID = Games.GameNo
WHERE GameID = '$NGnumber' ORDER BY DrawOrder";
```

In all posts i've seen, the solution is to create an alias on the column that has the same name, for instance:

```
$sql="SELECT Bets.AwayScore AS B-away FROM Bets
INNER JOIN Users ON Bets.UserID = Users.UserID
INNER JOIN Games ON Bets.GameID = Games.GameNo
WHERE GameID = '$NGnumber' ORDER BY DrawOrder";
```

But I have a lot of columns to select, if I write them all my SQL query will take forever to write!  Is there a way to create an alias while keeping `SELECT * from Bets` ?

Thanks!

Comment: See @juergend answer below. You can even put multiples without alias like Select Bets.*, Games.* From....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to select all columns of a table then use `tablename.*`

```
SELECT b.*, b.AwayScore as bet_awayscore, g.AwayScore as game_awayscore
FROM Bets b
INNER JOIN Users u ON b.UserID = u.UserID
INNER JOIN Games g ON b.GameID = g.GameNo
WHERE b.GameID = '$NGnumber' 
ORDER BY DrawOrder
```

Comment: So if I want to echo something, would I use something like `echo $rows['u.ColumnName'];` , `echo $rows['g.ColumnName];` and so on ?

Comment: When you select 2 columns that are named equal then you have to alias them

Comment: In the SQL query?  Could you give me an example?  My 2 columns with the same name are "AwayScore" and "HomeScore" in tables "Games" and "Bets"

Comment: Ok now AwayScore and HomeScore are being displayed but everything else is blank with my code `echo $rows['GameTime'];`, I even tried `echo $rows['g.GameTime'];` but no luck.  Do I still have to create an alias on any column I wish to read data from?

Comment: `GameTime` is from the `Games` table. You can use `g.*` to select all columns of the `Games` table. Or use `*` to select all columns of all tables in your select query.